# How do I use this jQuery plugin to delete a cookie?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

First, to show the cookie, I used code from [electrictoolbox.com](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-get-all-cookies/).

Then I made a form to add some cookie:

```
<form class="cokies" method="post">
<input class="query" name="q" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="save" value="saving">
<a>Delete Cookies</a>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cokies a').click(function(){
    $.cookie('q', null);
});

remember('[name=q]');
```

This function is from [komodomedia.com](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2008/07/using-jquery-to-save-form-details/):

```
function remember( selector ){
    $(selector).each(function(){
        //if this item has been cookied, restore it
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if( $.cookie( name ) ){
            $(this).val( $.cookie(name) );
        }

        //assign a change function to the item to cookie it
        $(this).change(function(){
            $.cookie(name, $(this).val(), { path: '/', expires: 365 });
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is, I can't work out how to delete a cookie.

Answer (score 14):

To delete the cookie, simply set the `expires:` to a negative integer value.

example:

`$.cookie(name, $(this).val(), { path: '/', expires: -5 });`

Comment: if it works give it a tick and others who come to this question knows the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

New versions of the Cookie plugin have come out, and provide the following convenient syntax:

```
$.removeCookie('q');
```

Comment: make sure to also set the path to the same path as you set the cookie originally: `$.removeCookie('q', { path: '/' });`

Answer (score 2):

Jquery cookie script has a bug .... It might be better to change the beginning of the script jquery.cookie.js:

```
jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
    options = options || {};
    if (value === null) {
        value = '';
        options.expires = -1;
        options.path = "/";

    }
 ....
```

In this case you will be able to delete a cookie as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`$.removeCookie("COOKIE_NAME",{domain:'.domain.com',path:'/'});`

Check the path and domain of the cookie and make sure you include those in the extra parameters with the `$.cookie` plugin.